# Remote Postgresql port 5400 listening but closed?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a remote Postgresql database on a Ubuntu server.

I've done the following to set it up for remote:

- In the postgresql.conf uncommented and changed this attribute to: **listen_addresses = ' * '**
- In the pg_hba.conf added these 2 lines to the bottom:

  **host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5**

  **host    all             all              ::/0                            md5**
- Changed the ip table with this command: ***sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT***

Note that it has actually worked earlier before but now I can't connect anymore. I can perfectly access the linux server via SSH in terminal and access the database. When I try to test the port it works in terminal like with: **telnet ipxxx.xx.xxx 5432** or via psql I always get 'Operation timed out' error. However it connects fine with port 22.

This is how it looks with netstat -nlp:
[image]

I don't have any real knowledge on network and ports and am at a loss here, spend many hours on this that should've taken little time. It's slowly draining my soul so any help is extremely appreciated.

Update:
I just found out that I can only access my school network ip, that's why I couldn't connect sometimes when I tried elsewhere. The server I hired I also got from school. Port 5432 is open when I enter go the school network. 
But it should listen to everything right with this?

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: First check you can telnet to it locally. Then enable iptables logging and check if it's actually blocked.

Comment: I can telnet it locally, I have seen the iptable logging file and I do see 3 UFW BLOCK all with id=54321. How would I unblock it? I have also more clues in my updated version on why it could connect before

Answer (score 0):

- is there firewall on on the server
- is there a firewall between A and B
- on the server can you connect to the db with psql on localhost
- on the server can you connect to the db with psql on the public ip
- on the remote box can you connect to the server using psql

Comment: My firewall status on ubuntu is currently: InActive and the firewall on my macbook is turned off. On the server I can connect with both localhost and the public adress. I can only login remote with psql with the internet connection of my school where I also hired the server, only then port 5432 is open.
Maybe I haven't properly set it up for remote, it's only is accessible from my school internet connection now.

Comment: looks like your school has the port blocked somewhere, ask them about your options

Comment: They said everything is open, unfortunately they weren't able to help, not directly at least